# Why can a suggested edit change while in review?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I reviewed an edit and rejected it, because it was wrong. I wanted to know what happened to this edit and checked the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3610609) in my activity - reviews. I was quite surprised, the edited question I saw there was not the one I rejected!

[image]

When I rejected it the code looked like:

```
String str1 = "My hobby is playing \"Tennis\".
// I am good at it. I love it. 
String str2 = "My hobby is playing \"Tennis\".
// I (Alex) am good at it. I(Alex) love it.
```

Why can the question change while it is in the review queue? The only possiblity I can think of is that Nick Wilson has improved it, but then he would have been the editor and not the guy who suggested it.

What happened here?

Comment: I am more dumbfounded by the edit summary ಠ_ಠ

Comment: "I editz zis for da reesun unknowz lolz" sigh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suggested edits have grace period. If the editor changes his/her edit while it's still during review (i.e. not rejected or approved yet) **the next reviewer will see only that updated edit** without any way to see the previous/original edit. (most likely there's window of 5 minutes or so, didn't check it yet)

I proved this using my loyal (and still clean ;)) sock here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15042

As you see, suggested edit was changed after being submitted.

Whether it's a bug or by design, I can't really say. If by design, likely same reason as we have grace period elsewhere: to allow the author to fix small mistakes quickly without being shamed.

Comment: OK, generally I think the grace period is a good thing, but in this case ... I am not sure. Maybe the reviews on the previous version should be removed then, so that the changed post has to get 3 new reviews.

Comment: @stema agreed. If a bug it should be fixed, if by design we should start feature request asking to change the behavior. I would prefer blocking edits by the user who suggested the edit after the first review action was done, showing message like "your edit is being reviewed, can't change it anymore"